# NSFileManager Authentication

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, file-handling

I need to create a directory using NSFileManager into another directory that requires an administrator's password to allow a change in its content. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [`BLAuthentication`](http://blog.laurent.etiemble.com/index.php?post/2005/12/05/36) class.